# call WebService in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

I'm doing a project in asp.net with a web services. My web services and my asp.net project is separate and my asp.net project have a reference of my web services

I'm using visual studio 2008 framework 3.5 and my service web is in vb.net

I want to call the web methods of my web services in JavaScript

my script manager is declared

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptManager" EnablePageMethods="true" >
    <Services>
           <asp:ServiceReference path="http://localhost:2931/ServiceCompas.asmx"/>
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

the JavaScript functions

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function test() {
            alert('test');
            Service1.Liste_Carte(Onsucced);
        }

        function Onsucced(resultat) {
            alert('je suis passée');

        }

    </script>
```

service1 is the class of my Webservice

and I call the function test with my button

```
<input name="btnRecherche" class="btnRechercher" type="button" value="Rechercher un emplacement" onclick="test()" />
```

The problem is : JavaScript say Service1 is not defined but why? What's the problem?

Comment: We don't mind a little French around here, as long as the important bits are in anglais.

Comment: Very minor point: the JavaScript convention is to capitalize the name of functions you intend to use as a constructor, so `Onsucced` should be `onsucced` (or, well, `onsuccess`).

Answer (score 0):

Double-check whether you have access to the namespace for Service1.  You may have to use the ASP.NET namespace in the call, which would make it something like:

```
ServiceCompasNamespace.Service1.Liste_Carte(Onsucced);
```

See http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2006/12/28/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-service-proxies.aspx for an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="WebService.asmx/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Since I'm trying to solve the same problem, I can see this might be missing somewhere according to: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2006/12/28/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-service-proxies.aspx (the above link)

that being said, the service.asmx/js file can't be found... is there something specific to be done for it to be generated?

EDIT, it works for me, here's the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="WebService.asmx/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callback(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        };

        function HelloWorld() {
            WebService.HelloWorld(callback);
        };
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test" onclick="HelloWorld();">
        click this
    </div>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
      <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService.asmx" />
      </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to cross-domain security restrictions (different ports result in different domains as far as the browser is concerned).

It looks like you're using the development webserver. When debugging locally, your separate projects will run on different ports which will produce this problem.

For testing, you could try using IIS and creating your applications with different top level directories, so they can both run at the same time on port 80.